# sql - count records per weeks using timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the table named 'tasaciones' which has 2 columns 'record' and 'fecha' (fecha is timestamp).

```
record  | fecha
-----------------------------

record1 | 2015-10-09 11:24:52

record1 | 2015-11-09 11:31:52

record2 | 2015-17-09 11:37:17

record3 | 2015-25-09 12:03:31

record3 | 2015-26-09 12:03:31

record4 | 2015-10-10 12:23:25

record4 | 2015-11-10 12:27:25
```

I need to make weekly report by counting records per weeks from the date of first record until the current time.
I found something like this but even if this is what I need, I don't know how to write 'while' to `echo` the data.

```
SELECT year(fecha), datepart(week, fecha), count(*)
FROM tasaciones
GROUP BY year(fecha), datepart(week, fecha)
```

I want to get results like this:

week 1: 15 records

week 2: 10 records

week 3: 25 records

week 4: 25 records

Comment: What are the results of your query and what are your desired results?

Comment: I updated my question, thanks for attention

Comment: I updated my question once again

Comment: @JaniBolkvadze As i understand your question. you want php code to print the result return by the query.

Comment: yes, I don't know how to print the results

Comment: there is no `DATEPART` in mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `DATEPART()` in MySQL.. You can use [YEARWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) instead. So your query should look something like this.

```
SELECT count(*) as numRecords, YEARWEEK(fecha) as weekNum
FROM table
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(fecha)
```

Echoing out the results depends on the api you are using.

### PDO:

```
$query = $SQL->prepare('...query here...');
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['tags'];
}
```

### MYSQLI:

```
$qry = '...query here...';
$results = $mysqli->query($qry);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['numRecords'], $row['weekNum']
}
```

**Note**: I didn't post a way to do this with the **Mysql_** api since that has been deprecated and is vunerable to sql injection along with a whole lot of other problems. You should switch to **PDO** or **Mysqli_** if you haven't already

Comment: Hi, your query prints out 84 | 201540,
35 | 201541,
51 | 201542,
75 | 201543

Comment: sum of 84 + 35 + 51 + 75 is exactly the sum of records in the table

Comment: @JaniBolkvadze ok is there an issue?

Comment: the first record has timestamp of 28.08.2015 so there're more than 4 weeks

Comment: @JaniBolkvadze that can't be possible. look at the docs for yearweek. whats the smallest and the largest dates in the table?

Comment: You're right, now I see that the lowest date is 2015-10-09 10:54:39

Comment: @JaniBolkvadze yep sure thing! glad I could help :) any more questions feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `DATEPART` in mysql try using `week` instead.Do not use `*` unnecessarily in count it will slow down your sql.

```
$query = "SELECT week(fecha) as w, count(record1) as cnt FROM tasaciones GROUP BY  week(fecha)";

    $res = $mysqli->query($query);
$table="<table><thead><th>WEEK</th><th>RECORDS</th></thead><tbody>";
    while ($results = $res->fetch_assoc()){
      $table .="<tr><td> Week:" . $results['w'] . "</td><td>" . $results['cnt'] . "records</td></tr>";
    }

 $table .="</tbody></table>";
echo $table;
```

Comment: WEEK RECORDS
records
records
records
records

Comment: It prints 4 rows, without numbers

Comment: Week:40 84records,
Week:41 35records,
Week:42 51records,
Week:43 75records

Comment: @JaniBolkvadze then what is the issue.

Comment: Thank you, your code also works, I already acceptad the answer of John Ruddell but your code works as well.. Thank you once again for the attention

Comment: "Do not use * unnecessarily in count it will slow down your sql." Do you have numbers to back that up? Or is this optimized out in modern SQL servers? Because i've tested it with queries that take 14 seconds and could not find any difference (aside from random fluctiations)

Answer (score -1):

Concerning the first part of your question, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT year(fecha), datepart('week',fecha), count(*)
FROM tasaciones
GROUP BY year(fecha), datepart('week',fecha)
WHERE fecha <= timestamp(now())
```

Concerning the second part of your question (i.e. "how to write 'while' to echo the data"), I guess you mean how to print the data from your query in PHP. So, assuming you're using PDO:

```
$query = "SELECT year(fecha), datepart('week',fecha), count(*) FROM tasaciones GROUP BY year(fecha), datepart('week',fecha) WHERE fecha <= timestamp(now())";
$sql = $db->query($sql);
while ($results = $result->fetch()){
  echo $results[0] . ' ' . $results[1] . ' : ' . $results[2] . 'records.<br />';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code snippet for your question.

```
$sql = "SELECT year(fecha), datepart(week, fecha) as week, count(*) as week_total_record
FROM tasaciones
GROUP BY year(fecha), datepart(week, fecha)";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['week']." : ".$row['week_total_record'];
}
```